# AWS Glue progress DB read progress

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to dump about 35 Gb of data from an Oracle DB to S3 and I'm using Glue to do it (for very strong/pertinent reasons).

My df looks like this:

```
datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    'oracle',
    connection_options = {......
```

Unfortunately, the job has been running for more than 2 hours now and I have no indication of how many DB rows have been processed.

Is there any way to enable some sort of progress indication of how many DB rows have been processed/added to the DF at any given time while the frame is still building?

[EDIT]: Also, is there any way to optimize the reads by having parallel connections/reads against my data source?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable parallel read in JDBC connection options while creating dynamic frame.
Refer to the AWS documentation.
[Reading from JDBC tables in parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/run-jdbc-parallel-read-job.html)